# Why reducer in createSlice can't change state in different ways?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm curious to know what's the difference between these 2 ways of changing state (commented and non-commented)? The first one leads to problem when dispatches doesn't work well. Why is that?

```js
export const correctiveSlice = createSlice({
  name: "corrective",
  initialState: initialCorrectiveState,
  reducers: {
    correctContent: (state, action: PayloadAction<CorrectiveState>) => {
      // This code doesn't work
      // state = {
      //   item: {
      //     id: action.payload.item.id,
      //     text: action.payload.item.text,
      //   },
      //   edit: action.payload.edit,
      // };

      // This code works
      state.item = action.payload.item;
      state.edit = action.payload.edit;
    },
  },
});
```

I'm doing classic todo-list app, but instead using Context API I'm using `redux-toolkit`/`react-redux` libraries. When I tried to use first way to change state, it didn't change.

Comment: Hey, please don't link the code like that, instead copy it as text to the question. For the proper formatting with [fenced code blocks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Markdown-Syntax.html#fenced-code-blocks). If you put `javascript` just behind the leading three backticks, you'll even get the according syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign `state` to a completely new object with `state = {...}`, you're *not* modifying the passed `state`. Instead, You're re-assigning new local variable to a new value, i.e. changing the reference. The underlying methods only have access to the `state` they've passed to the reducer method, which remains unchanged. Actually, this is not a matter of `Redux` or `React`, but a basic behavior of `JavaScript` - or any language which doesn't work with explicit pointers.

To modify the underlying variable, you either have to modify it's properties as you did with `state.item = action.payload.item` etc., or by merging it as described [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/javascript-merge-objects), for example. Modifying the state is only allowed if you're using `redux-toolkit`, though!

Alternatively, you *return* the new state with something like `return action.payload` instead of modifying the passed `state`. In that case, the returned item will replace the previous `state`. This is a `Redux` feature.